# LocalizedColumn decorator in Sequelize and nestJs

Tags: sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I have a nestJs project in which every model has some Localized Columns like Name, address, etc .., and I want to declare a virtual value where I get and set the column depending on the user language, So instead of doing the below code for each Column:

```js
@ApiProperty({ type: String })
  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
  })
  nameEn: string;

  @ApiProperty({ type: String })
  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
  })
  nameAr: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.VIRTUAL(DataType.STRING, ['nameAr', 'nameEn']),
    get() {
      const appName = Locals[(this as any).$local || 'ar'];
      const column = _.camelCase(`name ${appName}`);
      const columnName = column;
      return this[columnName];
    },
    set(value) {
      const appName = Locals[(this as any).$local || 'ar'];
      const column = _.camelCase(`name ${appName}`);
      const columnName = column;
      return this[columnName] = value;
     }
  })
  name: string;
```

Is there any way to modify the @column decorator in sequelize-typescript to do this automatically something like this:

```js
@ApiProperty({ type: String })
  @LocalizedColumn({
    type: DataType.STRING,
  })
  name: string;
```